# ATMega328 not able to fully switch coreless motor on

Tags: power, motor, atmega328, mosfet

I'm having trouble regarding motor control in a project I'm working on.

It uses an ATMega328 DIP package on a PCB. The motors I'm using are small coreless motors and I'm trying to control them using Si2302ds N-MOS FETs. For the power supply I'm using a 3.7V(4.2V on full charge) Lipo. I've tested this setup with a promini before and the motors turned on and off just fine.

This time I'm having problems with controlling 1 motor out of the 4. I've attached 0.1uF caps across each motor terminal (see schematic). Them control pins used for the motors are pins 3,5,6,9. The problem occurs at pin 3. I tried running the blink program on pin 3 to pulse the motor on and off through the FET but all I get is a bit of clicking from the motor.

Things I've already checked relating to the circuit :

1. FETs are soldered on correctly and made sure they aren't defective.
2. Motor works fine prior to connecting it to the circuit.
3. Disconnected the FET and motor from pin 3 and checked the output.
   It works fine on its own.

The puzzling thing is that only 1 motor (at pin 3) seems to struggle to come on. The rest work just fine. Also if I try and turn all 4 motors ON, it doesn't work. But if I turn only the 3 working ones on and keep the non-working one off they turn on perfectly.

Is the problem occuring due to noise generated by the motor? What could be the problem? I've attached the schematic to this post below.

[image]

Comment: Can you interchange any pins / FETs / motors?  Eg, exchange the pin 3 and 5 connections to see if another pin drives 3's FET ok, or if 3 can drive another FET ok, and similarly for motors.

Comment: Indeed, mix and match would be a good idea.  If you mean "pager" type moters they can fail in interesting ways resulting in very high current drain.  Also use a scope, or failing that a speaker with DC blocking cap to make sure the pin in question is constantly on - perhaps try a simpler program that does nothing but drive that pin and enter an infinite loop.

Comment: What's your clock speed?

Comment: jwpat7 I have tried driving that motor with Pin 7 but without any luck. Though that is only a digital pin and without PWM capability.

Comment: canadiancyborg I'm using a 16MHz crystal

Comment: Can you post a higher resolution schematic? That is almost unreadable.

Comment: "_I have tried driving that motor with Pin 7_": Using 7 introduces another variable. What would be more useful is to interchange the motor on pin3 with one from 5, 6, or 9 - the working combinations. Then see if the problem follows the motor or the pin.

Comment: Nick Gammon Sorry for that, I've updated the post with a clear picture of the motor control circuit.

Comment: @JRobert and Chris - I removed the chip form the PCB, then put it into the Arduino board and ported the o/ps to the chip socket in the PCB. The circuit functioned fine in this setup but failed again after putting the chip into the PCB. So is it some sort of under-powering issue with the ATMega328 ? I'm using a 3.7V 500mAh  25C lipo. This supply worked well when I tested this setup on a breadboard. My understanding is that the ATMega328 brown out is set at 2.7V so the chip also should've been able to function.

Comment: A couple of thoughts: 1) The issue only happens with the chip on the PCB so the PCB environment is suspect. The PCB itself was used in both trials, right? If so, its hdw is prob OK. 2) On the Arduino, did you power with 5V? From USB? Then the PCB/LiPo combo might be starved for power. 2) Pin 3 is the only one of the 4 using Timer-2 for PWM. That might mean that in that chip, T-2 is closest to its margins, so is the first one to fail. Try testing the LiPo voltage for droop under load. 4) Try pin-10 instead of pin-3; it uses Timer-1. Definitely not a fix :)  but it might be instructive.

Comment: @JRobert No luck on pin 10 either! Yes the PCB was used in both cases. I'm not sure if it is a power issue anymore since even when I'm switching that single motor on it does not seem to work. I tried swapping chips but the problem still persists. When I cut the trace to the non-working pin, the other 3 motors work fine and even the unconnected pin3 works fine when I checked it with a DMM.

Comment: @SidharthM - let's take this to chat: http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/info/47641/atmega328-not-able-to-fully-switch-coreless-motor-on?tab=general